Does such a thing as $\lim_\limits{g(x)\to a} f(x)$ exists?
Does such a thing as $\lim_\limits{g(x)\to a} f(x)$ exists? I thought about this out of thin air while messing with limits on W|A, of course it didn't output anything when I tried, but I thought it was an interesting concept, at first I thought about $\lim_\limits{x^2\to 4}x$, and reached the the conclusion that $\lim_\limits{x^2\to 4}x = 2$, since $x = 2 \rightarrow x^2 = 4$, but I don't think my logic was correct there because what I did was basically $\lim_\limits{x\to2}x^2=4$. Then I decided to ask some of my professors if $\lim_\limits{x^2\to a} f(x)$ is something that exists, two of them said it might be $\lim_\limits{x\to a} \sqrt{f(x)}$, or it was $\lim_\limits{x\to a} f(\sqrt{x})$, now I'm not 100% sure what they said but no one was sure about this.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I don't think zkutch's interpretation is good enough.
Yes, the limit $\lim_{g(x)\to a}f(x)$ makes sense. For one variable functions, if you use $\epsilon-\delta$ definition, this limit exists and equal to $L$ if
$$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0,\forall x\in\mathbb R,(0<|g(x)-a|<\delta\Rightarrow|f(x)-L|<\epsilon).$$
You can prove that $\lim_{x^2\to a}f(x)=L$ iff $\lim_{x\to\sqrt a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to-\sqrt a}f(x)$ both exist and equal to $L$.
This notation is useful in several variables, for $f(x)$ defined on $\mathbb R^n$ we often write $\lim_{|x|\to+\infty}f(x)=0$ by saying $f$ vanishing at infinity:
$$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists R>0,\forall x\in\mathbb R^n,(|x|>R\Rightarrow|f(x)-0|<\epsilon).$$
In this case $g(x)=|x|$, which is also a function.
Another thing we often is the notation $\lim_{x\to\partial U}f(x)$ where $U$ is an open set $f:U\to\mathbb C$. Sometimes we often write it as $\lim_{\operatorname{dist}(x,\partial U)\to0}f(x)$ where $g(x)$ here is the inner distance function $g(x)=\inf_{y\in U^c}|x-y|$.
Update: Here is a notes copied from the comment below.
We need to be careful on the non-uniqueness of the limit if $g(x)\equiv a$, which is logically okay, although not elegant for practice.
For an "application" to the non-uniqueness, every function on $\mathbb Z$ is continuous, because the limit $\lim_{m\in\mathbb Z\to n}f(m)$ can be anything, in particular it can "equal to" $f(n)$. If you run the $\epsilon-\delta$, the assumption $0<|m-n|<\delta$ is empty if $0<\delta<1$, and everything after that can be put.
Update 2: There is another feature (which I really agree if you say it a bug as well) on the notation "$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$" itself when the limit is not unique. One could argue that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=(-)$ is a "uniary predicate symbol" where "$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$" stands for "$L$ is a limit of blablabla". It's just in most case we can avoid such discussion.
As an analysist, here is another case that can justify the non-uniqueness.
If we consider a sequence of measurable functions $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$, we have a notion $f_n\to f$ for converges in measure (I don't want to use almost everywhere convergence because it's not topological). Such $f$, if exists, is not unique but unique up to almost everywhere. We can certainly change $f$ to another function under a zero measure set and the limit notation still holds.
Although I agree it's not a prefect example because sometimes people instead take quotient space of the space of measurable functions.

Another application is a concise definition of Cauchy sequences: $\lim_{\min(n,m)\to\infty} |a_n - a_m| = 0$

What if we take a constant function $g(x)=a$ in your definition?

@zkutch Then any value $L$ will satisfy the limit condition, since the implication will always be vacuously true. Uniqueness of limits is not a given.

@zkutch If you stick to the definition, the limit can be any number because the truth table of logical conditional says "$\bot\to P$" is always true. That is why $\lim_{m\to n}f(m)=L$ holds for all $f:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb R$ and $L\in\mathbb R$, and hence every function on $\mathbb Z$ is continuous.

This is exactly what I wanted to draw your attention to - such a definition loses the uniqueness of the limit.

@zkutch That's not necessarily a bad thing - it could be a feature rather than a bug. Writing $\lim_{g(x)\rightarrow a} f(x)=L$ is then a stronger statement: this modified limit exists and it is unique.

@zkutch Read something more from pointset topology, you'll see that it is rather useful.

@Sambo I don't think $\lim_{g(x)\to a}f(x)=L$ implies the uniqueness of $L$. I would say the limit exists if there is (at least a) $L$ such that the sentence corresponding to "$\lim_{g(x)\to a}f(x)=L$" is true. That's unfortunately another feature.

@LidingYao: That's very confusing.  If the limit exists, and both $L = 0$ and $L = 1$ satisfy the definition, then $\lim_{g(x) \to a} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{g(x) \to a} f(x) = 1$, which appears to imply that $0 = 1$.

Not only case  $g(x)\equiv a$ is dangerous, but also all that cases, when for $g$ there is not deleted neighbourhood of $g$'s limit point in which $g(x)\ne a$.

@zkutch Again this is a feature in a higher level of math. And it does appear in certain course notes.

Not only uniqueness can be under dangerous, but existence also. Let's take $g(x)\equiv 0$ and put inside $f$ which is $0$ everywhere except point $0$, where it is, for example, $1$. Then limit of $f\circ g$ gives $1$, while limit of $f$ in $0$ is $0$. It’s unlikely that “higher” level considerations, along with the word “again,” will help justify such a definition, imo.

@zkutch In the calculus level I totally agree, that is also happen in the rigorous proof of chain rule: we need to apply some techniques to avoid $g$ crushing into the limit point.

@zkutch No worry. It's just what the context matters. If I am a calculus lecturer I would probably say no to this notation. as well But considering MSE is a public forum, it's more dangerous to say no than yes for broader audiences.

@LidingYao You raise a good point about the uniqueness, but I think Jesse is correct. Indeed, this is why we don't write $0/0$: there exists a number $x$ such that $0\cdot x = 0$, but it isn't unique, so we can't use notation for it.

A shortcoming of your definition it is that you assume $g$ and $f$ are defined for all $x\in \Bbb R$. This is unnecessary. The key requirement should be that $a \in \overline{g(\text{dom} f)}$. That is, for every neighborhood $U$ of $a$, there is some $x$ in the domain of $f$ which is also in the domain of $g$, with $g(x) \in U$. If this does not hold, you should consider the limit not to exist. It is uniqueness that is a feature of limits, and if it does not hold, then you need to use different terminology to discuss the set of limit points (as is commonly done in point-set topology).

Correct construction for your case can be considering by using limit of composition of functions:
Assume we have $\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x)=b$ and $\lim\limits_{y\to b}f(y)$, then in certain conditions we can claim $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(g(x))=\lim\limits_{y\to b}f(y)$
In your case, for simplicity let's consider only case for $\sqrt{a}$. Then $x^2\to a$ only when $x \to \sqrt{a}$. So, if we consider $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and having $\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x)=\sqrt{a}$ and assuming, together with some other conditions, that exists $\lim\limits_{y\to \sqrt{a}}f(y)$ we can write
$$\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(g(x))=\lim\limits_{y\to \sqrt{a}}f(y)$$
for continuose $f$ in point $\sqrt{a}$ last limit gives $f(\sqrt{a})$.

Sorry. I was paying attention to the OP saying $g(x)=x^2$. You are no longer responding to the OP. You wrote “$x^2\to a$ only when $x\to\sqrt a$.” How is this? Dismiss me as you wish, but writing incorrect mathematics does not help.

I'm a downvoter. I agree with Dr. Shifrin. The issue is that your "for simplicity" is wrong. That is not a restriction you are allowed to just impose.

Frankly, I'm confused by your answer. I'm not able to follow your reasoning, or even what you're trying to claim, especially in the last paragraph.

@A. Thomas Yerger. I can consider an example in any particular or general case - if everything written is mathematically correct, then there can be no complaints about mathematics. What do you want to say?

@Sambo. Can you, please, set concrete question?

But it is not mathematically correct. You are assuming that $x \mapsto x^2$ is an injective function. You cannot just say "for simplicity." You have to consider both.

No, @A. Thomas Yerger. I am not assuming $x\to x^2$ in general. I am considering case $[0,+\infty]\to[0,+\infty]$, so everything written is correct.  Indicate exactly the place in my answer where I admit that this is an injection and if cannot, then have the courage to admit the mistake. Or do you have other reasons for down voting?

But if the notation is to be meaningful the limit must apply to $x^2 \to a$ which occurs whenever either $x\to \sqrt a$ or $x\to -\sqrt a$.  When trying to explain I don't think we are allowed to toss it out.

@fleablood. If under "toss it out" you mean, that I am against to consider also $x\to -\sqrt a$, then you are in mistake: I am agree, that we need both. Only moment is that in my answer just for this moment is considered case $x\to \sqrt a$ and is shown result for it. Unique sentence which needs my answer to be added is "Same happened for $-\sqrt a$". I am waiting for something and then, possibly, shall add it. But to consider partial case is my right and it is not reason, as I understand, for down voting.

No.  By "toss it out" I mean "toss it out".  Of course you aren't against considering $x\to -\sqrt a$.  But you seem to think you are allow to "for the sake of simplicity" not consider it for a moment and you consider them as distinct cases.  You can't.


Translation gives me, that "toss it out" is same with "throw it away", which I understand as "against to consider", but all 3 is not true,  2. Numbers $\sqrt a$ and $-\sqrt a$ are distinct, if $a\ne 0$, so, I can call them different cases and consider firstly one of them, then another -  did I write somewhere that only  is $\sqrt a$ possible? Also, I can consider only one of them, leaving second to reader. (continuing)


(continuation) This is a common practice, I’m sure not only known to you, but also used by you in many cases. And what did you see that was special about me? 3. Considering  partial sequential viewing I can, of course,  call "for simplicity".
