Meaning of $\lim_{\rho (x) \rightarrow a}f(x)$
I was studying the Fréchet derivative of a function and came across the limit
$$ \lim_{\| h \| \to 0} \frac{\| f(x_0+h) - f(x_0) -Ah \|}{\| h \|}. $$
The problem is that I have never seen a limit like this. I mean a limit like $\lim_{\rho (x) \to a} f(x)$ (where $\operatorname{dom}(\rho) \subseteq \operatorname{dom}(f)$). I would like to know if I am right in saying that:
$$ \lim_{\rho (x) \to a} f(x) = L
\iff 
\left(
\begin{gathered}
\text{for each $\varepsilon >0$} \\
\text{there exists $\delta >0$ such that} \\
\text{for all $x \in \operatorname{Dom}(\rho)$ :} \\
\text{$\| \rho (x)-a \|< \delta \implies \|f(x)-L\|< \varepsilon$}
\end{gathered}
\right)
$$

Here is essential, that your $\rho (x)$ is norm. General cosideration can be find on
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4899256/does-such-a-thing-as-lim-limitsgx-to-a-fx-exists/4899268#4899268

you're right. The definition i gave is thus coorrect

Please avoid titles that consist of nothing but MathJax. They break some navigational shortcuts.

I strongly suspect that the inciting limit is actually a typo. $\lim_{|h| \to 0}$ can only mean the same thing as $\lim_{h\to 0}$, which is the common form of the definition of the Fréchet derivative (more specifically that $A$ is the unique linear transformation making the limit $0$). Likely the author was thinking of the quotient expression and absent-mindedly included the norm in the limit as well.
